# Проблема переноса сайта на хостинг

Tags: хостинг, hosting

Есть два хостинга **Ru-Center** и **Джино**.
Нужно на хостинг **Джино** разместить домен **"КУПИТЬХАЛАТ.РФ"**. Разместил. Залил один файлик - index.php.
Перехожу по ссылке: xn--80aawhhvwdcx0f.xn--p1ai (купитьхалат.рф), но он переносит меня на **Ru-Center** и выдает страницу заглушки.
Вопрос: эти два хостинга как-то связаны? Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: ваш домен зарегистрирован в ru-center. вам надо отключить загрушку и указать ip-адрес вашего нового хостинга в настройках DNS на nic.ru

Comment: Слабо в этом понимаю. Отключить заглушку? Вы имеете ввиду вообще убрать его с Ru-Center?

Comment: Я сделал его НЕ делегированным. Не знаю, правильно ли это

Comment: Нет, не убрать, он там зарегистрирован, он там и останется. Посмотрите там настройки DNS. Сейчас в качестве NS серверов там указаны заглушки, во первых надо что бы NS сервера стали другими, возможно так же ru-center, только не заглушки. И прописать "A" запись для домена с указанием IP-адреса на котором ваш хостинг

Comment: В любом случае джино это обычный хостинг. хоть он домены и предлагает, он регистратором не является. он домены так же заказывает через тот же ru-center или другого аккредитованного регистратора. а доменное имя и хостинг это две совершенно разные вещи

Comment: В общем, тут уточнили, есть хостинг Джино и домен на Ру центре, их надо связать
DNS-сервера на домене КУПИТЬХАЛАТ.РФ следующие:
statuspage1.nic.ru
statuspage2.nic.ru

Comment: в общем вам сказали именно то что и я говорю, вам надо на nic.ru в настройках домена выключить заглушку (тогда поставятся нормальные nic DNS сервера по идее) и прописать в настойках DNS "A" запись с ip хостинга

Comment: Я приостановил делегирование. Ошибся. Как можно восстановить его? Возможно ли это вообще?

Comment: наверняка можно. изучайте меню, если не помогает обращайтесь в техподдержку nic.ru